# If I do work on an object, does that increase or decrease its gravitational potential energy?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

I know that when an object A does positive work on another object B, object A loses energy and object B gains energy(there is transfer of energy from object A to object B) and when object A does negative work on object B, it gains energy and object B loses energy (there is transfer of energy from object B to object A).

Now, when we lift an object (standing on the Earth), we do positive work on the object and so the energy of the object should increase (and our energy should decrease) while the Earth by its gravitational force does negative work on the object and so the energy of the object should decrease (and the energy of the Earth should increase).

Now my question is, is the energy of the object increasing or decreasing, since it cannot be both at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why people answer the question in comments, but Farcher's answer is correct.  The Earth is not doing any work at all: separating two objects attracted by gravity increases the potential energy of BOTH objects.  If "you" do the separating, the energy is coming from converting chemical energy to mechanical in your muscles, not from the Earth.

Comment: A few issues here.  During the motion, both the earth and the object *are* doing work, but it is *internal* work.  Also, saying that the the potential energy of both objects increases obscures the fact that potential energy is defined only for *systems* of *two* particles (and systems built of multiple pairs).  One can't say that the potential energy of *a single object* increases, although we commonly do just that for objects near the surface of the earth.  I think this is a flaw in pedagogy.  If the subject were introduced properly, confusion like this would not arise.

Comment: @garyp: Thank you for the clarification about potential energy being for systems of two objects, not for isolated objects.  This should make the concept more clear to anyone trying to figure out a potential energy problem.